# How to check all checkboxes in a specific column javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a table with 3 columns, only the 1st and 3rd column of TDs have checkboxes. I have a button that says "SelectAllFirst" that puts a checkmark on all checkboxes in the first column only, the 3rd remains uncheked. How do I accomplish this?

I thought it would be something like this:

```
$("#mytable tr td:eq(0) input:[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true);
```

(but that doesnt do anything. Removing the "eq(0)" results in all checkboxes including the 3rd column to be checked)

Comment: what about removing the colon from between input and the square brackets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this should work,though I didnt try it out:

```
$("#mytable tr td:nth-child(1) input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

`td` is the cell, I guess you mean the row. Hard to tell without html though...

```
$("#mytable tr:eq(0) td input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a Fiddle for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/pwCKu/

I believe there are better ways to toggle the check. Just a proof of concept.

Comment: i misunderstood the question. sorry. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#checkAll").click(function () {
$(".check").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
```

});
This is the code for checking all checkboxes with a checkbox like "select all".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).